# How to show the number of active sessions?

Tags: playframework

For an intranet Scala-Play application I'm working on it would be interesting to see how many sessions are currently being served.

Is there a way to get this information that can then be neatly displayed in the interface? This Web Application is stateless and there is no database and login in place otherwise it would be trivial to do. I can only rely on the Scala-Play API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session's data is Map, you can use map.size to get session size.

```
def foo = Action { request =>
  request.session.data.size
}
```